# User files storage with laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm having trouble saving the file to the correct username logged in when the user upload a file.

I have this syntax:

```
 $file->move('../UserFolders/{[username}]/photos/', $name);
```

So what happens is that laravel create a folder called:

{[username}] instead of pointing to the logged username

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax might be incorrect.

```
$file->move('../UserFolders/{[username}]/photos/', $name);
                                      ^^
                                        `-- here
```

You open a curly brace, open a square bracket, then *close the curly brace*. Try nesting them as `{[username]}` (I assume {[]} is some Laravel magic, decoded by `move()`):

```
$file->move('../UserFolders/{[username]}/photos/', $name);
```

or if `$username` is indeed available in the local scope, simply

```
$file->move("../UserFolders/{$username}/photos/", $name);
```

(If a folder '{[username]}' gets created, then there is no such Laravel magic, and you should check the documentation).

Remember that **the code will not be evaluated** if you put it in **single quotes**. You need to enclose it in **double quotes**:

```
$file->move("../UserFolders/{Auth::user()->name}/photos/", $name);
```

or

```
$folderName = Auth::user()->name;
$file->move("../UserFolders/{$folderName}/photos/", $name);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the last solution worked great but I still have an issue with the view, when I get the list of pictures I click on it, the link does not reflect the actual username of the session.

Comment: That would be matter for a different question. Without looking at the code or knowing *how* the link *does not reflect...*, I'd venture that you need perhaps to store the picture's owner somewhere and display that value - *not* `Auth::user()->name` which is the *current* session owner - in the link. But I'm just guessing, and I may well be wrong. On a not entirely unrelated note, could I interest you in some question-asking technique tips?

Comment: Alright.. can you take a look at this code in this link : http://pastebin.com/U1t6CJj7

Comment: I have. Do not take this wrong, but -- I believe you need more experience with 'low level' PHP before continuing with Laravel. Here you're using a `$foldername` variable that has been long forgotten by the time you get to the list blade, and probably evaluates to an empty string. In *this* case, you need to persist it in the `store` controller - e.g. add an `owner` field to the `Image` class and init it from `Auth::user()` - and retrieve the field in the view where you now use `$foldername`. As it is, your code has a faint smell of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming

Comment: haha I loved your answer and I accept it with a big heart, indeed i'm new to  this framework and to PHP so I'm trying my best to understand things, also we should know that if a person doesn't make mistakes then how can he progress and learn from those mistakes anyway... thank you for your input brother

Answer (score 1):

Because your syntax is wrong you should do

```
 $file->move('../UserFolders/'.$username.'/photos/', $name);
```

Because you are doing this in your controller thus variables are accessible with a $ only and you have to concatenate it with the string

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still, laravel is creating a folder called: {{username}} any idea

Comment: Edited my answer and are you sure {{$username}} is a valid variable with username stored in it if you are trying to access the name of current logged in user then use {{Auth::user()->name}}

Comment: again, it created a folder with name {{$username}} and I tried {{Auth::user()->name}} and {{Auth::user()->username}} but still nothing